# How can i set custom error message for Rule::in field in validate method in laravel 8 controller

Tags: laravel, validation

I have been trying to set custom error messages for fields validation in laravel controller.

I have set the custom messages but i can't figure out how to make Rule::in field work.

I am pasting the controller below .

```
public function registerNewAnkda(Request $request)
{
    $attr = $request->validate([
        'game_id' => ['required','numeric'],
        'market' => ['required',Rule::in(['Kalyan', 'Time','Ratan','Main','Milan'])],
        'DoN' => ['required',Rule::in(['Day', 'Night'])],
        'OoB' => ['required',Rule::in(['Open', 'Bandh','Jodka'])],
        'type' => ['required',Rule::in(['Ankda'])],
        'selection' => ['required','numeric',Rule::in(['0', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])],
        'stake_amt' => ['required','numeric'],
        'to_win_amt' => ['required','numeric'],
    ],
        //Below code is used to display custom validation error messages!
        [ 'game_id.numeric' => 'The :attribute should be Unique and Numeric ! MSG FOR PINKA !',
          'selection' => 'Rule::in should be Single Number ! E.G - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'
        ]
        
    );
```

The Rule::in field custom message is not displaying ! so any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($attr->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($attr);
}
```

To display all errors at once

```
@if($errors->any())
    {!! implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) !!}
@endif
```

To display error under each field.

```
@error('firstname')
    <div class="error">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: This can be definetely used to display errors in blade file BUT i need this in controller as it is an API and need to display the error messages in json! so i used this method of implementing custom error messages in validate() method itself.

Comment: So just add the value from variable $attr in your json.